# What is the reward for spelling out "Blast" in Peggle Blast?

Tags: peggle-blast

When you clear a level in Peggle Blast,  (don't judge me - the original is a *classic*!) you can "light up" the letters that spell out "blast" when your remaining balls are all shot into the gamespace.

But it's not obvious what you get when you spell the whole word.  What's the reward?